# Slicing the power BI report only by slicers not images

Tags: powerbi

I have a scenario where I am using date and country slicers along with maps in my report along with some stacked charts.

When I click on the map for one country it filters the data based on that country I have selected but the filter is not reflected in slicers.

Is there any way that I can use the map only to display the counts without having select, in other words, no selection allowed on the maps?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Format** tab and select **Edit Interaction** option as shown in the below image. Now select your **Map** visual and set Filter = None in other visuals you don't like to interact when click on the Map.

[image]